# How to use TODO tags in org-mode without defining headings?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, todo

When I'm writing down a few notes in org-mode :

```
note 1
note 2
note 3
```

And then want to make 'note 2' a `TODO` item, I need to turn it into a headline, as such :

```
note 1
* TODO note 2
note 3
```

But now, 'note 3' belongs to the 'note 2' headline. The only solution I know is to turn the other notes into headlines as well.

```
* note 1
* TODO note 2
* note 3
```

But that's tedious.

I've tried

```
# TODO note 2
```

But that doesn't work either.

How to get todo-keyworded items without actually changing the outline ?

Comment: You probably want to check inline tasks.  (require 'org-inlinetask) then `org-inlinetask-insert-task' to insert an inline task.

Comment: It also seemed to me tedious first, but making each note is a headline is the way to go, because then you can easily add more info to individual notes. Alt+Enter and Alt+arrows make it quite simple to create a headline quickly when necessary.

Comment: Thank you both!
@bzg: Sounds good. Unfortunately I'm a total emacs noob, so I haven't been able to follow your steps. I tried
    M-x  (require 'org-inlinetask) 
but emacs answered 
    [No match]

Comment: @Tom: Thanks. I knew about Alt+arrows but not about Alt+Enter
Very helpful!

Comment: @user1323995: (require 'org-inlinetask) sounds like something that would need to be placed in your .emacs file. (Alternatively, to just test it out, put that line in a scratch buffer, place your cursor after it and type M-x e to evaluate it). Then you should be able to run the command org-inlinetask-insert-task

Comment: @BeSlayed That should be `C-x e`
@user1323995 Take a look [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html); there are some really nice video tutorials in that list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your question seems to be [here in the Worg FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#closing-outline-sections).

As BeSlayed mentionned, you need to put `(require 'org-inlinetask)` in your ~/.emacs file (don't forget `M-x eval-buffer` the first time) (or you can do `M-x load-library RET org-inlinetask`, also…).

Then, an inline task is a heading with >15 stars, as described [here](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob;f=lisp/org-inlinetask.el;h=01f861e611aee4c24fcf7184ea191962be83be70;hb=HEAD), and you can use `C-c C-x t` to insert them.

Comment: Note to future self setting up another machine: Yes, Dotan, this is the comment that you've been googling an hour for. Don't forget `eval-buffer` this time! And say Hi to Meirav, Maayan, and Ofek from your past self.