# stack-like document structure in org mode

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, there is no way to end what you are writing at a given heading level without beginning a new heading, but I would often like to go back to a higher level heading.  For instance, I will be writing some section of a document, and I want to put an extended aside in the middle of some part of it.  What is the best way to do this?  I have been using lists, but they are treated differently from headings in various ways.  For instance, list items don't have a headline/body distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Inline Tasks](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#closing-outline-sections) if you absolutely need to have a subsection inserted into the middle of a document.

This question has come up several times (the link contains threads from the mailing list regarding this), as well as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718401/how-to-use-todo-tags-in-org-mode-without-defining-headlines) among others.

Since Org is an outlining tool there is no way to return to a higher level outline (there is no defined 'end' to a given section short of another headline.

To return to an equivalent levelled headline you could create a headline without a title.

Comment: Thanks.  (And thanks to fni, who made the same suggestion.)  Sorry for asking a question whose answer is so easily available.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at "inline tasks"?